# Ping sweep syntax via CMD.exe

Tags: cmd, ping

I am trying to create a command that does a ping sweep then outputs the replies to ping_result.txt. Here is what I've got. However, it doesn't actually populate the file with output.

```
(for /L %a IN (1,1,254) DO ping /n 1 /w 3 192.168.2.%a | find "Reply") > ping_result.txt .
```

Any solutions using this method of redirection and grouping?

Comment: Why not just pipe the ping results to file first and then search in file?

Comment: I'm trying to more complex operations via single line cmds

Comment: your line works fine for me (after adapting the base-IP to my network and replacing "Reply" by "Antwort" because of my German Windows). You should filter for "TTL" instead of "Reply" to make it independent of localization. Are you running it from command line or is it in a batchfile?

Answer (score 4):

I think that your parentheses are on "wrong" place giving different results. This is what you might have in mind and at least works for me.

```
(for /L %a IN (1,1,254) DO ping /n 1 /w 3 192.168.2.%a) | find "Reply" > ping_only_replies.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This issues a command for each address so you need to append to the file and not just redirect to it.

(for /L %a IN (1,1,254) DO ping /n 1 /w 3 192.168.2.%a | find "Reply") >> ping_result.txt

Comment: wrong. The whole `for` loop is within parantheses (a block), so you can redirect the whole output with just `>`.